# Ensure tests for a form those test in PHP concurs with the Javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, forms

Is there a mechanism to ensure that the tests to ensure that the data given by the user has the same tests applied by both the client (browser) and server.

i.e. Is it possible to just construct one bunch of tests (say in PHP) and automatically generate the same tests at the other end (Javascript in this example). Of course this could be the other way around.

**EDIT**

You would like the Javascript on the browser to validate the form. But the user can and may turn that off. To ensure that the data is valid you need to get the server code (PHP) to perform those tests. Is it possible to just create one set of tests to ensure validity of the data regardless of the language - thus reducing development effort and also enable any changes to the validity of the data to be mirrored?

Comment: Your example is unclear.  This is lack of clarity stems from the simplicity of HTTP that forces the server and user to have separate and entirely unrelated roles.

Comment: i think you mean validate data the same way on JS as on PHP? and have the same code for both? sure, that's easy to code. but a generator for code from one to the other.. not so sure. i think it's better to hand-code the equivalent. some functions in JS don't exist in PHP and vice versa

Comment: He means he wants to validate for example field A B and C in a form. He wants to know if he can program it once for both server and client side, and it would work for both.

Comment: @Joseph - Exactly, Truth - Just to generate the same tests and not spend the effort in coding the same tests in two languages, but also if during development those tests should not diverge.

Comment: When I used to code in ASP.NET there were validators for the form elements. You only specify the kind of validation on the server side and it does the client side automatically. I think that's what he is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only similar set of tests I can think are `regex` expressions that may be used in both client and server-side codes in the same way. Other test may be length of variables,checking for  special characters.

But remember that your JavaScript has so much vulnerabilities due to unavailability of script tag parsers, sql injection prevention methods. You cannot fully test the validity of data unless you have filtered several crucial data with the server.

JavaScript validation although will provide better user experience, primarily what its role should be when it comes to data inspection. Because you choose not to irritate your users with the lost of their form data due to incorrect inputs, you use `alert`, `localStorage` and ajax methods to check asynchronously with a server feedback.

Hence, as far as I know you cannot fully duplicate a data inspection method between the two client side and server side program.

Comment: Thank you - Javascript is for a better user experience - hence if they click *OK* on the client (with Javascript enabled) the data should just go through. But the server needs to ensure its own integrity. i.e. check the data and do not trust the client. Would it be handy to have the same tests at both ends without having to code in two languages?

Comment: in other words, strengthen your server-side checks. you should **never** rely on client-side validation. they are just there for quick-validation, and not serious validation.

Comment: Client side, like i said, is only for showing off. But with the ajax you can show off and at the same time have server maintain its operations on the client. Hence, some operations that do no perform on client side can be checked with server side as the user types with `onkeyup` event. But since, JavaScript doesnt have `PDO statements` or `mysql_real_escape_string` that you have to check while inserting data into database, php validation is the way to go. Hence, use client-side validation only because you dont want the users to a see a page reloading (i.e, better user experience)

Comment: I **never** believe in anything coming from the client. The question is about to reduce effort and also achieve in a good user experience in that the data they enter can be checked in the same way as the server. **THE SERVER IS THE MASTER AND HAS TO DOUBLE CHECK THE DATA**. But for a good user experience it is better they press the *OK* button and it should just go through (as the server tests are the same)

Comment: Sure, thats fine if you wanna validate on both ends. Like I said, `regex` is the only way where you can achieve code similarity. These expressions operate the same way on both ends. So if you want to optimize validations, set up the same regex expressions such as name, password validation and so on.

Comment: @ladiesMan217 - Would it be nice to generate the code from PHP into Javascript to check the form before it gets sent down the pipe to the server? i.e. automate the checking code ate that the browser end so that those checks match?

Comment: Some of it, but not all of it.

Comment: @ladiesMan217 - But is there software to generate the tests from the PHP code - i.e. have a *makefile* that creates a part of the javascript to do those tests. This would help in productivity and also in ensuring a consistent use of those regexs

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no. There were things like [xajax](http://xajaxproject.org/) that had javascript being generated on server side and thus you could write serverside code that would affect frontend, and reuse some of the validation code. But I consider it a bad practice. You have to write backend and frontend tests separately, because they differ in too many ways, not to mention speed and too tight coupling

Comment: In what ways should the testing that the input strings should differ?

Comment: You might have dependency on unexpected things.. like checkbox somewhere. To pass it to backend you'd have to add extra info.. the more complex interaction becomes, the harder it is to understand and maintain

Comment: Kurpov - But the data from the browser (possibly being checked by Javascript) needs to undergo the same tests and checks when it hits the server (PHP) end. i.e. that is my question, how to harmonize those checks and balances?

Comment: You should have client-side unit tests if they have complex logic. Use  JSTestDriver for example http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: @Kurapov -Yes I know - Just would like to reduce the effort somewhat and ensure consistency between the PHP code and the Javascript code as mush as possible - including if things change and ensure that those changes either get mirrored (best) or highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

That is going to be a little project for me - take a form with a variety of tests, generate the Javascript and PHP to check some of the validity (ie. regexs, lengths ...).

Might be worthwhile.